# Cannot debug when logged in as a user other than the administrator

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have acustom sharepoint page.

on my machine I can debug the code normaly by attaching to the w3p process when I'm logged in as the administrator user.

when I log in with another user and try to debug I always get access denied page in the sharepoint and the dubug exists.

is there a way to debug the code while logged in with another user

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are trying to attach to sharepoint's processes which run under some specific account, using a non-admin account. You simply don't have enough privileges to do that.

I'd suggest that you keep logged in as administrator and consider the two choices:

- run Internet Explorer through `runas` command under the desired user account:
  `C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:contoso\sampleuser /savecred "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"`
- open Internet Explorer as administrator and use the SharePoint's "sign in as different user" feature.

Comment: Thanks naivists
but this is already what I do
I run IE as admin and use sign in as different user
when I do so I can't debug the code
so is there anything else can be done

Comment: alright naivists I judged on this method quickly
Actually your first method to run the IE under that user is correct and it worked for me
tjanks